# Problems installing CULMUS for Hebrew rendering: Map files not recreated. updmap: Updating ls-R files

Tags: mactex, hebrew, culmus

I tried installing CULMUS following the instructions here: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/

However, the last step always fails and I cannot render any Hebrew text.

I am using Mac OSX.

I ran the command:

```
sudo make CULMUSDIR=/Users/bjmongol/Documents/culmus-latex-0.7-r1 TEXMFDIR=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

and

```
sudo make install CULMUSDIR=/Users/bjmongol/Documents/culmus-latex-0.7-r1 TEXMFDIR=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

This is the log:

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=culmus.map
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/bjmongol) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

I'm not sure what this means. I made sure that I pointed to the right folders. I also tried doing `sethebrew` and `unsethebrew` when typing in TexShop. But it didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

### Update: when I try to render the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}
\fontfamily{nachlieli}\selectfont 
\begin{document} 
מה קרה
\end{document}
```

these warnings show up:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 57.

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/he8enc.def)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/nachlieli/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.

(./latex_test.aux
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/he8nachlieli.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `HE8/nachlieli/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 2.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/he8cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def) [1{/usr/local/te
xlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./latex_test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ){/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/culmus/he8.enc}</usr/local/te
xlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/public/culmus/DavidCLM-Medium.pfa>
Output written on latex_test.pdf (1 page, 8534 bytes).
SyncTeX written on latex_test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on latex_test.log.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: On the website, it is explicitly tell that it work only for Linux, not Mac Os X. Why not just installing the oft/ttf font, and call them using \setmainfont?

Comment: Don't ever use `sudo make`. `sudo make install` is necessary if you don't follow upstream's non-privileged user advice. (Understandable as MacTeX doesn't.) But `sudo make` is just horrible.  If that's in the instructions, the instructions are either written by an idiot or an act of idiocy by a non-idiot. Either way, they should be ignored.) This is general advice: `sudo make` should never be necessary and is always wrong.

Comment: Your value for `CUMULUSDIR` is wrong unless you really did install the fonts into the source directory of the LaTeX package. Do you have the fonts? You need them to build the support package.

Comment: @cfr I think you were right. I installed the required fonts into /usr/local/fonts/culmus but it still doesn't work. When I render in Latex it just shows up as a bunch of question marks. I've updated the question to show the log.

Comment: @cfr Of course I changed the CULMUSDIR to /usr/local/fonts/culmus

Comment: Please update your question with the current commands and output. Is the map line added to the map file? Does the document look correct? What you're getting are only warnings.